# Change SameSite attribute for FedAuth cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies, iframe, samesite

I have a difficulty to change the SameSite attribute on an ASP.NET MVC application. Here is the scenario:
I'm trying to load my ASP.NET application inside an iframe and because of the changes in Google Chrome 80+ I need to set the SameSite attribute for the cookies to be able to use the authentication cookie in the iframe. I followed this link [SameSite Cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite)

and applied the changes but for some reason, this doesn't change the SameSite attribute for the FedAuth and FedAuth cookie.
Here is the code for creating the session cookie:

```
SessionAuthenticationModule session = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
SessionSecurityToken sToken = session.CreateSessionSecurityToken(principal, null, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24), isPersistant);
            session.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(sToken, true);
session.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sToken);
```

**web.config**

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="28672" targetFramework="4.7.2" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" sameSite="None" requireSSL="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms  requireSSL="true" cookieSameSite="None"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" /> 

<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler mode="Default" requireSsl="true" persistentSessionLifetime="0.06:00:00" path="/"/>
</federationConfiguration>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to working with wsfed, but adding this to my `Global.asax.cs` seemed to work for me:

```cs
void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SignedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (string key in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
  {
    if (key.StartsWith("FedAuth"))
    {
      var cookie = Response.Cookies[key];

      cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
      cookie.Secure = true;
    }
  }
}
```